# For what positive integers $p$ and $q$: $(p+1)!+(q+1)!=(pq)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I tried this problem using brute force and got the answers as $(3,4)$ and $(4,3)$,but is there a way to solve this question?

Comment: I'd argue by inequalities. you can assum $p \geq q$ which gives you $p - 2 < q$ cause otherwise you'd get $(p+1)! > p^2 q^2$. I suppose the rest should follow easily considering $p=q$ and $p=q+1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WLOG, Assume $p \ge q$. Then, $p^4 \ge (pq)^2 = (p+1)!+(q+1)! \ge (p+1)!$.

We can show by induction that $n^4 < (n+1)!$ for all $n \ge 5$.

Hence, we must have $q \le p \le 4$.

Now, just test all possible pairs with $1 \le p,q \le 4$.

Comment: great argument.  $(4,3), (3,4)$